# Is there a Chrome extension like DownloadHelper for Firefox?

Tags: linux, video, browser-addons, flash, chromium

I search something like [DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/), a tool to download Flash videos. It should work on Chromium (Linux). Any link?

Comment: Why this question was downvoted ?

Comment: Probably because it doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin for Chrome called [flv_download](https://bitbucket.org/m.23/flv_download/wiki/Home).

> Flash Video Download (flv_download) is a Google Chrome extension
>   allowing to download flash videos from web sites (like YouTube,
>   Dailymotion or Xhamster).

It has a long list of supported sites. You can download it from the link provided there, and just drag it into Chrome as far as I know, or open it with Chrome.

Comment: Alternatively, most flash videos get saved into a tmp directory, and you just move them out of there.

Comment: It does NOT work on Google Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m. Look at these screenshots: http://i.imgur.com/xBXzK3b.png, http://i.imgur.com/m0TNN8O.png, http://i.imgur.com/MN3qk7U.png. When clicking on the extension's icon, it pops up a window saying "Working...", but nothing happens. So this extension is unusable. Btw., why does it want to communicate with an external site (`wisevid.com`)?

Comment: @Sk8erPeter this answer is well over a year old, things do break over time.

Comment: @SimonSheehan: yepp, that's correct, but this way others can see my comment, so maybe they won't waste their time to try this non-working extension like I did. If you know a better alternative for Chrome since then, you could update your answer, thanks in advance. :) (You'd get more upvotes. At least from me.) I've been searching for a Chrome extension which is similar to [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/), but unfortunately I haven't found any which is comparable to that yet. (I don't really like Firefox, but I love VDH.)